# How to access a ComboBox in Datagrid programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` as such added in XML as the code bellow. Now, how do I access the `ComboBox` named `Combo1` programatically? I am not able to access it normally using the name `Combo1`. I want to be able to retrieve it's value, or change itemssource etc.

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="133,94,23,116" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="dgData_SelectionChanged">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Subject}" Header="Subject" Width="*"/>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="100">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <ComboBox Name="Combo1" Height="22" ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find what you need here. However, I will say that doing this isn't the best of practices...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-ii.aspx

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
            return (childItem)child;
        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try to use something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T :       DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i reccomend u read more about MVVM pattern.