# Display value of combobox in Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following code:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="174" Width="156" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="100">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Name="Combo1" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding SubjectSubList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SubjectSubList}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public class TicketInfo
{           
    public List<string> SubjectSubList { get; set; }
}

static List<string> resolution = new List<string>();
static List<string> codec = new List<string>();

resolution.Add("1");
resolution.Add("2");

codec.Add("3");
codec.Add("4");

List<TicketInfo> ticketsList = new List<TicketInfo> 
{
    new TicketInfo{ SubjectSubList=resolution},
    new TicketInfo{ SubjectSubList=codec},               
};
```

I am able to get the objects displayed separately in two different comboboxes, but I have NO idea now I can retrieve the value selected by the user. "Selecteditem" is bound, but how do I retrieve the values in code-behind?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you're code is insufficient and is not a complete example I can base any code on. There doesn't seem to be any connection between the `TickerInfo`-class and the XAML you have posted.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion on how to bind comboboxes in a Datagrid to a list and retrieve their value?

Comment: @Omid it seems you don't understand the basics. you should get acquainted with binding on simple collections then get to combo then to a combo in a datagrid.. this is too far a leap for you at the moment

Comment: alright will look into it more, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access a ComboBox in Datagrid programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184641/how-to-access-a-combobox-in-datagrid-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

`SubjectSubList` in the `DataContext` you assign to the control will be updated when the selection changes. The property must have both a public setter and getter since the update is two-way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a SelectedItem Property, so if your combobox is a list of strings then you can have a selectedItem property like this:

```
  public string SelectedSubject { get; set; }
```

, Then in xaml bind 'SelectedSubject' to the selecteditem:

```
        <DataTemplate>
           <ComboBox Name="Combo1" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding SubjectSubList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubject}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Then at any time in your code you can access SelectedSubject and its value should be whatever is selected in the combobox at that time.

But now you need the selected item of a certain row in the datagrid? Well then you will either have to pass the selectedrow in code parameter and try to access that value for that selected row, or have SelectedSubject as a property in your SubjectSubList, which would have to be an object of some sort. Hope this helps.

Comment: I really wish it would work, but after doing "MessageBox.Show(SelectedSubject);", I see that the string is empty after changing the value :/

Comment: try adding:  ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged   after the SelectedSubject in xaml